# Drupal Backup and Restoring

Tags: drupal, backup, recovery

So I wrote this script that basically creates a sql dump of the the drupal databases as well as created a tar of of the www directory. I took this off the server and put it on my local machine. I want to take these backup files and test to see if the backup is stable as well as to learn the process.

My problem is that I can't find any clear instructions on how I would be able to do this. Can anyone give me a hand?

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: I ended up creating a folder in /var called www with all the drupal stuff in it and made a sql databses that contained all the information. How do I actually access the website?

Comment: The backup_migrate module could potentially make the process simpler. http://drupal.org/project/backup_migrate

Comment: If your local web server is set up correctly, it is accessible via http://localhost

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have a LAMP stack installed on your local machine.  In addition, you'll need to modify the settings.php file to change the database connection strings to match your local enviornment.  Youi may also need to modify the $base_url variable in the settings.php.

THis would not be necessary if you were simply restoring, but since you're moving the install it is required.

Comment: Okay, I did all of that. It took me a while with the Apache server but everything is working on that end. The only problem I have is that when I go to localhost, the apache welcome page comes up as there is no index page in the html folder. What do you suggest?

Comment: Did you copy your drupal site to the htdocs directory.  If drupal's index.php is in the same folder that is your htdocs, and it still isn't loading then you need to update your apache config to have index.php set as a default document page.